# Coordinate plotting from csv file using matplotlib and pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, plot

[This is the csv file](https://github.com/authman/DAT210x/blob/master/Module5/Datasets/CDR.csv).
*Im not sure,but these plots ought to show the telephone tower coordinates which person made call from(or something).*

The problem is;after slicing the dataframe succesively,for some reason,x and y axis coordinates becomes like this (-0.030,0.020)

```
user1 = user1.loc[(user1.DOW == 'Sat') | (user1.DOW == 'Sun')]
user1 = user1.loc[((user1.CallTime < "06:00:00") | (user1.CallTime > "22:00:00"))]
```

If i slice the df like above,the result is this:
[image: Problematic Plot]

But if i delete the second slice(time slice),plot becomes normal.
But if i put that slice right behind of another plot,two plots becomes normal for some reason:

```
user1 = user1.loc[(user1.DOW == 'Sat') | (user1.DOW == 'Sun')]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(user1.TowerLon,user1.TowerLat, c='g', marker='o', alpha=0.2)
ax.set_title('Weekend Calls (<6am or >10pm)')

user1 = user1.loc[((user1.CallTime < "06:00:00") | (user1.CallTime > "22:00:00"))]
user1.plot.scatter(x='TowerLon',y= 'TowerLat', c='g', marker='o', alpha=0.2,title="The Last Plot")
```

[image: weekend calls normal]
[image: Normal Last Plot]

As you can see,coordinates becomes normal for some reason.
I dont know much about plotting.
I dont know why the second slice caused problems.
Thank you.